# Flutter: Change PaginatedDataTable page navigation position

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, paginateddatatable

I'm currently using PaginatedDataTable on my project. However, I'm having trouble because I want to customize the footer from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

as you can see on the second picture, the pagination located on the left side of the table instead of the middle like the first picture. Is there any way I could do it?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Did you get the answer for this?

Comment: As far as i know, there is no solution for this since it is from the Flutter itself and there is no such attribute to arrange the pagination panel position. Correct me if I'm wrong.